# How to convert below sql-query which has union into queryDSL

Tags: sql, querydsl

I'm trying to convert below query into Query-DSL.
I don't know how to populate actual result set from it. How to write the below query in spring & querydsl. Please help. I am new to QueryDSL.

```
 SELECT * FROM
--First part of union
          (SELECT V.ID AS VID,
            V.MODEL,
            V.VIN,
            V.EXTERIOR_COLOR,
            V.LICENSE_PLATE,
            V.CURRENT_LOCATION,
            V.NOTES,
            L.DATE_OUT  AS DAYOUT,
            L.DATE_IN   AS DAYIN,
            NULL  AS HOLD,
            ''   AS REASONS,
            NULL AS ADATE,
           FROM PFIS_VEHICLE_DETAILS V,
            PFIS_CONTACT C,
            PFIS_VEHICLE_CONTACT_LOAN L
          WHERE C.ID          =L.CONTACT_ID
          AND V.ID            =L.VEHICLE_ID
          AND L.LOAN_TYPE_ID IN (1,5)
         UNION
    -- Second part of the union fetch from data for status-Id=4
          SELECT V.ID AS VID,
            V.MODEL,
            V.VIN,
            V.EXTERIOR_COLOR,
            V.LICENSE_PLATE,
            V.CURRENT_LOCATION,
            V.NOTES,
            NULL               AS DAYOUT,
            NULL               AS DAYIN ,
            S.ON_HOLD_TILL     AS HOLD,
            S.REASONS_FOR_HOLD AS REASONS,
            S.ANTICIPATED_DATE AS ADATE,
           FROM PFIS_VEHICLE_DETAILS V,
            PFIS_VEHICLE_DETAIL_STATUS S
          WHERE V.ID     =S.VEHICLE_ID
          AND S.STATUS_ID=4

        )
```

Comment: Some one pls help in writing querydsl

Comment: What is it that you're struggling with? Have you read the [Querydsl Reference Guide](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/)?